# Scala streaming peak detection with reactive events

Tags: scala, playframework, stream, reactive-programming

I am trying to work out the best way to structure an application that in essence is a peak detection program. In my line of work I have been given charge of developing a system that essentially is looking at pulses in a stream of data and doing calculations on the peak data.

At the moment the software is implemented in LabVIEW. I'm sure many of you on here would understand why I'd love to see the end of that environment. I would like to redesign this in Scala (and possibly use Play if I was to make it use a web frontend) but I am not sure how best to approach the initial peak-detection component.

I've seen many tutorials for peak detection in various languages and I understand from a theoretical perspective many of the algorithms. What I am not sure is how would I approach this from the most Scala/Play idiomatic way?

Obviously I don't expect someone to write the code for me but I would really appreciate any pointers as to the direction I should take that makes the most sense. Since I cannot be too specific on the use case I'll try to give an overview of what I'm trying to do below:

- Interfacing with data acquisition hardware to send out control voltages and read back "streams" of data.

  - I should be able to work the hardware side out, but is there a specific structure that would be best for the returned stream? I don't necessarily know ahead of time how much data I'll be reading so a stream that can be buffered and chunked would probably be appropriate.
- Scan through the stream to find peaks and measure their height and trigger an event.

  - Peaks are usually about 20 samples wide or so but that depends on sample rate so I don't want to hard-code anything like that. I assume a sliding window would be necessary so peaks don't get "cut off" on the edge of a buffer. As a peak arrives I need to record and act on it. I think reactive streams and so on may be appropriate but I'm not sure. I will be making live graphs etc with the data so however it is done I need a way to send an event immediately on a successful detection.
- The streams can be quite long and are at high sample-rates (minimum of 250ksamples per second) so I'd prefer not to have to buffer the entire stream to memory. The only information that needs to be permanent is the peak voltage data. I will need a way to visualise the raw stream for calibration purposes but I imagine that should be pretty simple.

The full application is much more complex and I'll need to do some initial filtering of noise and drift but I believe I should be able to work that out once I know what kind of implementation I should build on.

I've tried to look into Play's Iteratees and such but they are a little hard to follow. If they are an appropriate fit then I'm happy to work on learning them but since I'm not sure if that is the best way to approach the problem I'd love to know where I should look.

Reactive frameworks and the like certainly look interesting and I can see how I could really easily build the rest of the application around them but I'm just not sure how best to implement a streaming peak detection function on top of them beyond something simple like triggering when a value is over a threshold (as mentioned previously a "peak" can be quite wide and the signal is noisy).

Any advice would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: This sounds exactly what reactive streams are made for. Check out this presentation by Viktor Klang and Roland Kuhn from ScalaDays 2014 http://parleys.com/play/53a7d2c3e4b0543940d9e53a/chapter0/about

Comment: Thanks for the quick response! This was one of the talks I saw that made me think they'd be appropriate. Unfortunately I don't know well enough how I'd be able to build the peak analysis part with them - if it was a simple threshold check (if value > threshold generate or map event) I'd be okay but how do I look at potentially overlapping sections/windows in a reactive stream and then output to a new stream the peak data after analysing each "buffer"?

Comment: @porl - can you live with approximate answers or do you need "exact" values of the peak in each window ?

Comment: There is an element of error in all the measurements due to the noise and drift of the background levels so I can't say they need to be "exact" but the closer the better. The current algorithm is quite simple and essentially starts from a point that the threshold is exceeded and then reads ahead until the value drops back underneath (or a width is exceeded in which case the drift is recalculated).

Once this buffer is created it is split into three and the maximum value of the middle part is compared to the average value of the two outside parts. This value is considered the height of the peak

Answer (score 1):

This is not a solution to this question but I'm writing this as an answer because of space/formatting limitations in the comments section.

Since you are exploring options I would suggest the following:

1. Assuming you have a large enough buffer to keep a window of data in memory (`W=tXw`) you can calculate the peak for the buffer using your existing algorithm. Next you can collect the next few samples data in a delta buffer (`d`) (a much smaller window). The delta buffer is the size of your increment. Assuming this is time series data you can easily create the new sliding window by removing the first delta (`dXt`) values from the buffer `W` and adding `d` values to the buffer. This is how Spark-streaming implements `reduceByWindow` function on a DStream. `Iteratee` can also help here.
2. If your system is distributed then you can use stream processing systems (Storm, Spark-streaming) to get better latency and throughput at the cost of distributing the system.
3. If you are really resource constrained and can live approximate results that bounded I would suggest you look at implementing a combination of probabilistic data structures such as [count-min-sketch](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Count%E2%80%93min_sketch), [hyperloglog](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HyperLogLog) and [bloom filter](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bloom_filter).

Comment: Thanks for the tips, I'll look into the different options. I think the first one is roughly what I'm after. Will that work easily with something like reactive streams?

Comment: @porl - yeah it will work better with reactive streams. One of the features that Reactive Streams (and currently not supported by other Scala streaming frameworks) is the ability to deal with back pressure (see - http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Backpressure_Routing) But to start with it should be fairly easy to prototype and do some measurements based on your data rates, resource availability and frame sizes. As I said before Iteratee will certainly help.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion. I'm thinking that reactive streams will be the way to go.